# Programmatically set checked item in CheckListBox

Tags: c#, checklistbox

I'm trying to set programmatically checked item in checklistbox according to some criteria. This is code:

```
int chItm = 0;

foreach (DataRowView row in chLBDatumi.Items)
 {                
     if (row["DatumGO"].ToString().Equals(myListItems[chItm].ToString()))
     {
          chLBDatumi.SetItemChecked(chItm, true);
     }
     chItm++;                
 }
```

But it throws Exception:

> List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator
>   can only be used if the list does not change.

Is there any other way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chLBDatumi.Items.Count(); i++)
{                
    if (chLBDatumi.Items[i]["DatumGO"].ToString().Equals(myListItems[chItm].ToString()))
     {
         chLBDatumi.SetItemChecked(chItm, true);
     }
    chItm++;                
}
```

Comment: There is error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'" on chLBDatumi.Items[i]["DatumGO"].ToString()

Comment: Check if this works: `chLBDatumi.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().ElementAt(i)["DatumGO"]`